# Speed-up mex files in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a big loop that I need to compute many times in my code and I thought that it would be possible to speed it up using MATLABcoder. However, the mex file version of my code (the code for the function is attached below) ends up being slower than the m-file. I compiled the code using MINGW64 compiler.

I tried different compiler settings (played with coder.config) and different memory specifications but without any success.

```
function    v_d = test_code(q,v_exp,wealth,b_grid_choice,k_grid_choice,nz,nk,nb)
%#codegen

% Inputs
% q is an array of dimension [nz nk nb]
% v_exp is an array of dimension [nz nk nb]
% wealth is an array of dimension [nz nk nb]
% b_grid_choice is an array of dimension [nk nb]
% k_grid_choice is an array of dimension [nk nb]
% Typically, nz/nk/nb is an integer (currently up to 200)

v_d = coder.nullcopy(zeros(nz,nk,nb));

    parfor ii = 1:nz          
            q_ini_ii = reshape(q(ii,:,:),[],nz);
            v_ini_exp_ii = reshape(v_exp(ii,:,:),[],nz); 
            choice = q_ini_ii.*b_grid_choice - k_grid_choice;

            for jj = 1:nk
                for kk = 1:nb 
                    % dividends at time t
                    d =  wealth(ii,jj,kk)  + choice;
                    % choosing optimal consumption
                    vec_d = d + v_ini_exp_ii.*(d>0);
                    v_d(ii,jj,kk) = max(vec_d,[],'all'); 
                end
            end
    end
```

When I run this code when `nz`=`nk`=`nb`=`100`, the m-file takes 2.5s while the generated mex file takes 7.5s. I tried using both MATLABcoder app as well as the `codegen` command

```
codegen -O enable:OpenMP test_code -args {q,v_exp,wealth,b_grid_choice,k_grid_choice,nz,nk,nb}
```

I also played with `codegen.config('mex')` but with little impact on the performance.

---

When I test the speed of the above code I simply generate these matrices using `randn` command and then pass them into the code. Interestingly, when I generate these matrices *inside* the function then this has no effect on the speed of the m-file but speeds-up the mex file almost 10 times (so three times faster than the m-file)! This suggests to me that there is a way to speed up that code, but despite my effort I couldn't figure it out. I thought that memory allocation could be behind it, but my attempts with playing with dynamic memory specifications did not lead to any gains either...

Comment: To speed up your code, turn your loops around: the inner loop should be over the first index, the outer loop should be over the last index. This processes the data in storage order and therefore optimizes cache usage.

Comment: Also, a manually-written MEX-file is likely faster than what `codegen` produces.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, changing the order of the loop did not improve performance. I guess the only way to speed it up is to write this piece of code in C++ and then compile it rather than rely on codegen.

Comment: Is this code the "big loop" or is this function the code that is called often in the "big loop"? I'm not sure if `parfor` is a good idea in a mex-function (I don't even know if that works...). It will likely set up a new pool every time you call the function, causing an overhead. The MATLAB code may be faster, because the parallel pool is still open

Comment: @max This code is a "big loop," but in the actual code it will be within a while loop. Right now, I was just trying to learn a bit about mex files using part of the function I am trying to speed up. As far as I know, parfor works in mex. When I switch it off using -O disable:OpenMP then the mex code is substantially slower (and I also see low CPU utilization in task manager). I see your point about matlab pool, but when testing the pool was opened and I can always set a timer for it before running a code so that it is opened when the loop is run.

Comment: @max: `parfor` has a different meaning when generating code, it instructs the coder to generate OpenMP instructed code.